# An iPhone has been detected, but it could not be identified properly

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, windows, ios, error

Why do I get the following message in iTunes when syncing my iPhone(s)/iPad(s) to iTunes wirelessly on Windows Vista Ultimate?

> An iPhone has been detected, but it could not be identified properly.  Please disconnect and reconnect the iPhone, then try again.

Whenever I sit down at my Windows machine after being away for a while with iTunes running, I get several of these popups I need to dismiss before I can do anything in iTunes.

Comment: Tempting as it might be to point at Vista and laugh, I think it may be more useful if you were able to provide details of the version numbers for both iTunes and your iOS devices.

Comment: iOS 5.1 (but it's been happening since iOS 5 beta)

iTunes 10.6.0.40

Comment: I just performed an upgrade to the windows PC.  It's now running a clean install of Windows 7 and the latest iTunes.  All iPhones/iPads have been upgraded, and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to Uninstall iTunes, get rid of it entirety.

Reinstall from [Apple](http://www.apple.com/uk/itunes/)

Plug your iPhone in

It should now work fine.

If not follow the online troubleshooting assistant on [Apple's website here](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/assistant/itunes/)

Comment: Plugging in always works fine.  It's only the wireless-sync functionality which causes these errors.  I have tried uninstalling and re-installing in the past, although not recently

Answer (score 0):

Disabling wireless syncing is what fixed the problem for me. My theory is it has something to do with the pass code lock. It doesn't like it if you try to plug it in and sync with it locked by a pass code. I bet its the same thing with wireless. I will have to leave the pass code lock off over night with iTunes running and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: disabling wireless syncing is not 'fixing the problem' :(

Comment: I have same issue. I have iPhone 4 (7.1.2) using iTunes 12 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I logged out of iTunes, iCloud, on all devices, then logged in again. Fixed the problem